# Select only some columns by their average

Tags: mysql

I have a table with lots of columns. The allowed values are just 0, 1, 2, and I need only the columns where all the values are not 0 or 1. Practically, with a table like this

```
|Time      | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
|timestamp |   0  |   1  |   1  |   0  |
|timestamp |   1  |   1  |   1  |   0  |
|timestamp |   1  |   2  |   1  |   0  |
|timestamp |   2  |   2  |   1  |   0  |
|timestamp |   2  |   1  |   1  |   0  |
|timestamp |   1  |   1  |   1  |   0  |
```

my SELECT statement should return the columns "Time, "val1" and "val2".
I’m not able to find a solution and I even not able to think where to start from. All solutions coming in mind are immediately discarded since all function and transformation (where, join and so on) all require the column name to refer to.

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: you need dynamic sql for this

Comment: but I think you mean "not all the values are 0 or 1", not "all the values are not 0 or 1"

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I need that the query doesn't return the columns in which the values are all 0 or all 1. Exactly as for the example.

Comment: For dynamic sql, how can I create and store the query that can be called from outside? I use phpmyadmin and I request data via Grafana

Comment: What does `select version();` show?

Comment: 10.4.22-MariaDB

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't nkow this feature. I think following some tutorial I'll be able to use it. Could you please gve me some tip on how to set the procedure in order to get what I need.? Thanks so much

Comment: not sure what you are asking.  you do need either to do multiple requests to prepare and execute and deallocate your dynamic sql or do them in a begin block, but the begin block does not need to be in a procedure in modern mysql/mariadb versions.

Comment: maybe make an attempt and show it in a new question saying how you want to use it and what specifically you are having trouble with in getting it working